# Find whether a component is redirected from another component in angular

Tags: angular, routes, components

I'm using route to navigate between components.
Say I'm in the HOME component and navigate to the LOGIN component without any query params. Is there any way by which we can identify in the LOGIN component whether I was navigated from another component?

The reason we have lots of modules and users can open the LOGIN component alone or through navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The app component is never destroyed no matter where you route to, so this logic will work irrespective of any navigation that happens, so the logic should be places on the app component!

You can listen to router events and then filter out all the navigation end events, then pairwise will emit the last value and the current value, then you store it in variables of a component, or on a service and then solve your issue!

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((x) => x instanceof NavigationEnd), // filter out only the navigation end event
        startWith(null), // set an initial value
        map((x) => x && x.url), // get only the necessary value
        pairwise() // emit both the previous and current value
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('navigation succeeded', event[0], event[1]);
        this.previousPath = event[0];
        this.currentPath = event[1];
      });
  }
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-event-ecc5zc)

Comment: Dont think this will work AFTER the user was redirected. You need a separate service to monitor navigations all the time and store prev/current routes...